# Get browser history folder path in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a code in javascript do creation for new image file on the client side, I am looking for pattern to save this file without suffering from permissions problems, so I decide to save it in the browser history folder, so I want a code telling me the browser history path.

any contribution will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: this is not a tutorial site, you can ask questions when you stuck on your approach. but without trying how you get any  issue.

Comment: The standard Browser/DOM JavaScript interfaces provide no access to such information.

Comment: The browsers I regularly use (Chrome and Firefox) don't even *have* a "history folder". They both store history data in a database file.

Comment: I build application that scan image and send it to the server, I used VintaSoft ActiveX control to that, but it needs to determine the path for saving scanned image. so I want to save this file without suffering from permissions problems...Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for pattern to save this file **without suffering from
>   permissions problems**, so I decide to save it in the browser history
>   folder

- This is not hacking information site
- Accessing client without permission is bad practice any way
- This site does not provoke bad practices
- The answer that you would get *here* is: *You can't do that with JS*

Comment: sorry, but you understand my question in bad way, so let me tell you about my application. I build application that scan image and send it to the server, I used VintaSoft ActiveX control to that, but it needs to determine the path for saving scanned image. so I want to save this file without suffering from permissions problems...Thanks anyway...

Comment: @kaitoked: Thanks for pointing out the context of your question but unfortunately I don't think there is a way around it